# eas login with access token

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I have an expo app, I need to run `eas build`.
Before that I needed to log in to the expo account but I have signed up with Google, so I don't have a password.
I have created a new auth token from expo.
But I don't see how can I use this auth token to login from the console.